# How to use RANSAC method to fit a line in Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, error-handling, ransac

I am using RANSAC to fit a line to my data. The data is 30X2 double, I have used MatLab example to write the code given below, but I am getting an error in my problem. I don't understand the error and unable to resolve it.
The link to Matlab example is
https://se.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ransac.html

```
load linedata
data = [xm,ym];
N = length(xm); % number of data points
sampleSize = 2; % number of points to sample per trial
maxDistance = 2; % max allowable distance for inliers
fitLineFcn = polyfit(xm,ym,1); % fit function using polyfit
evalLineFcn =@(model) sum(ym - polyval(fitLineFcn, xm).^2,2); % distance evaluation function
[modelRANSAC, inlierIdx] = ransac(data,fitLineFcn,evalLineFcn,sampleSize,maxDistance);
```

The error is as follows

> Error using ransac Expected fitFun to be one of these types:
>
> function_handle
>
> Instead its type was double.
>
> Error in ransac>parseInputs (line 202) validateattributes(fitFun,
> {'function_handle'}, {'scalar'}, mfilename, 'fitFun');
>
> Error in ransac (line 148) [params, funcs] = parseInputs(data, fitFun,
> distFun, sampleSize, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets read the error message and the documentation, as they tend to have all the information required to solve the issue!

> Error using ransac Expected fitFun to be one of these types:
>
> function_handle
>
> Instead its type was double.

Hum, interesting. If you [read the docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ransac.html) (which is always the first thing you should do) you see that `fitFun` is the second input. The error says its `double`, but it should be `function_handle`. This is easy to verify, indeed `firLineFun` is double!

But why? Well, lets read more documentation, right? [`polyfit`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html) says that it returns an array of the coefficient values, not a `function_hanlde`, so indeed everything the documentation says and the error says is clear about why you get the error.

Now, what do you want to do? It seems that you want to use `polyfit` as the function to fit with `ransac`. So we need to make it a function. According to the docs, `fitFun` has to be of the form `fitFun(data)`, so we just do that, create a `function_handle` for this;

```
fitLineFcn=@(data)polyfit(data(:,1),data(:,2),1);
```

And magic! It works!

Lesson to learn: **read the error text you provide, and the documentation**1, all the information is there. In fact, I have never used `ransac`, its just reading the docs that led me to this answer.

1- In fact, programmers tend to reply with the now practically a meme: RTFM often, as it is always the first step on everything programming.